# All occurrences substring in the string

Tags: haskell

I need a function to find all indexes of substrings in the string. Below you can find my code, but I am just wondering if there is a better way of doing it:

```
-- find index of substring in string
--      index_of_substring "so" "unsomesome" -> Just 2
--      index_of_substring "to" "unsomesome" -> Nothing
index_of_substring :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
index_of_substring _ []  = Nothing
index_of_substring sub str = case List.isPrefixOf sub str of
    False -> fmap (+1) $ index_of_substring sub (tail str)
    True  -> Just 0

-- find all occurences of pattern in a string
--      all_occurrences_of_pattern_in_string "so" "unsomesomesome" -> [2,6,10]
all_occurrences_of_pattern_in_string pattern s = helper pattern s [] 0
    where helper pattern s result last_idx = case index_of_substring pattern s of
            Just n -> helper pattern (drop (n + 1) s) (result ++ [n + last_idx]) (last_idx + n + 1)
            Nothing -> result
```

Comment: Do you have to implement it yourself? There is a ready made one [here](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/KMP-0.1.0.2/docs/Data-Algorithms-KMP.html).

Comment: My quick list-decomposing solution was wrong. Yeah, you should just use KMP, [ain't gonna get better than Knuth](http://xkcd.com/342/)...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say that it can be done simpler, at least.  Unless the point was to write your own algorithm from scratch (which I don't think is the case since you're using `Data.List.isPrefixOf`), you can simply leverage `Data.List.elemIndices` to shorten the number of checks you have to do:

```
indicesOfSubStr :: String -> String -> [Int]
indicesOfSubStr []  _   = []
indicesOfSubStr sub str = filter (\i -> sub `isPrefixOf` drop i str) $ head sub `elemIndices` str

indexOfSubStr :: String -> String -> Maybe Int
indexOfSubStr = listToMaybe .: indicesOfSubStr where (.:) = (.) . (.)
```

So here I use `elemIndices` to get all the indices of the first character of `sub` in `str`, then filter out the indices that don't align with where `sub` isn't a prefix starting at that index.  That solves the problem for finding all indices.

Then we can simply leverage this function for `indexOfSubStr`.  I could have written the function as

```
indexOfSubStr sub str = listToMaybe $ indicesOfSubStr sub str
```

And in fact, it's a whole 8 characters shorter that way, but I usually have the `(.:)` operator defined already and who doesn't like point free?  If you're confused about what it does (the definition is somewhat cryptic, as is the type signature), it essentially just composes a single argument function with a two argument function.

Comment: Of course, this one gets extremely inefficient in cases like `indicesOfSubStr "ab" "aaaaaaaaacaaaaaaaaaaaay aaaaaab aaa baaaacabl"`.

Comment: @leftaroundabout Of course, but that's worse case performance.  There are other optimizations one could do, but it's no replacement for the KMP algorithm mentioned above.